# simple library project with playframework 2

Tags: playframework

I was wondering what the best approach would be to create a simple library project with playframework2 or sbt.

The project would be contain several java classes with no web dependencies, and would be included in a few different play projects as a library jar.

Is there a way to create a stripped down play or sbt project to do this that will create a small jar?

I saw there are sub-projects in play/sbt but this library project would be utilized in more than one application, and will likely be built and published to a maven repository as an artifact.   Hopefully the project setup would easily be included in a continous build/integration environment.

Thanks in advance,
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way is to write a Play module.  They are very easy to create. See this blog: http://www.objectify.be/wordpress/?p=363

To use the module, an apps' build.sbt or build.scala would include your module as a dependency.